# Postgres query - update field in json column with text type

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a column in my postgres DB called `metadata` which stores a JSON string, and the type is `TEXT`.

I'm trying to run a query to update a field named `myCount` inside the JSON. I'm using Spring Boot and JDBC.

```
String query = "UPDATE " + mTableName + " SET metadata = jsonb_set(metadata::jsonb, '{myCount}', ?)::text" +
                " WHERE scope = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setInt   (1, myCount);
        preparedStmt.setString(2, scope);

        // execute the java preparedstatement
        return preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

I got the following error: `ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, integer) does not`

Any ide ahow I can run a query that updates the `myCount` column inside the JSON?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name still issue - ` ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], integer) does not exist
`, about the jsonb, becuase of the in memory database that does not support json in tests

Comment: "*because of the in memory database that does not support json in tests*" which means you will never be able to test if you store valid JSON in the database. I am also pretty sure that this in-memory database also doesn't support `jsonb_set()`, so how are you going to test this code?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 9.5.9

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Let's focus on the issue, I have the same error when the column is `json`(`function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], integer) does not exist`)

Answer (score 1):

> function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, integer) does not

Tells you that you are trying to call the function with an integer value as the last parameter. But the function is defined as `jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], jsonb)` so you will need to convert the integer value to a JSONB value:

```
SET metadata = jsonb_set(metadata::jsonb, '{myCount}'::text[], to_jsonb(?))::text"
```